# how to pass values from python code to variable of robot framework

Tags: robotframework

I'm beginner in robot framework. I want to pass values from python file to variable of robot framework, but still can't work successfully.

**`globe.py`** is my python file and it's very simple.

```
a = 'this is testing'
```

below is test case configuration as robot required

```
*** Setting ***
|Variables|globe.py

*** Variables ***
|${myTest}|${a}
```

but robot throw error :

> "Error in file: Setting variable '${myTest}' failed: Variable '${a}' not found."

could you give some suggestion on that?

[here is screen about my execution steps and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBGRl.png)

Comment: @A. Kootstra, i modified my configuration like yours, used the tab delimited approach, still cant' work.   add screen about my execute steps and result, please take a look.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your example does work. I use the tab delimited approach, but that shouldn't be the cause.

```
*** Setting ***
Variables   globe.py

*** Variables ***
${myTest}   ${a}

*** Test Cases ***
A Test Case
     Log To Console    ${myTest}
```

This resulted into this response from Robot Framework which appears to be what you're looking for.

```
Suite Executor: Robot Framework 3.0 (Python 2.7.9 on win32)
==============================================================================
MyLibrary                                                                     
==============================================================================
MyLibrary.Test                                                                
==============================================================================
A Test Case                                                           this is testing
| PASS |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MyLibrary.Test                                                        | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
MyLibrary                                                             | PASS |
1 critical test, 1 passed, 0 failed
1 test total, 1 passed, 0 failed
==============================================================================
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try to import the variables .py file prior to use..

```
Import Library   <yourPythonFile.py>
#use variables from python variables file after successful import..
```

Answer (score 0):

The other workaround is using **--variablefile** option of robotframework.

**Test_varaibles.robot**

```
*** Settings ***
*** Variables ***
*** Test Cases ***
print message to console
  print msg
*** Keywords ***
print msg
  log to console ${msg}
```

Declare a variable **msg** in a python file

**variable.py**

```
msg='Hello!! This is First msg!'
```

To pass a variable file, we need to pass –variablefile or -V as a command line argument to pybot

run below command

```
pybot -V variable.py Test_variables.robot
```

**Result** 
[image: Using --variablefile]

For more descriptive details, you can also refer below

https://automationlab0000.wordpress.com/2018/11/20/how-to-pass-python-variable-file-in-robotframework/